# Actionbar disable title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title

Can someone explain why the hiding of title doesnt work with this code?

```
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

but if doing this, then it works

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);  // hides action bar icon
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
```

im a java developer before and just a newbie in android. just curious why things work out this way.

Comment: plz post your stack trace

Comment: post complete code the definition part

Comment: Please leave reasons for downvotes, especially as this is a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Use actionbar.setTitle("");
Instead of  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);